# NSDateformatter returning nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

My NSDateFormatter is retuning nil. This is an example string that I want to parse: `@"6/23/11 0:42"`

and this is the format i am using:     `[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"MM-dd-yy HH:mm"];`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: returning nil from what method? If it is from `setDateFormat:` it is ok, as it is a `void` type method. Does it **become** nil after this call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date string has different format: @"MM/dd/yy HH:mm" - try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The method you specify is defined as:

```
- (void)setDateFormat: (NSString *)string
```

It always returns `nil`. It just sets up the formatter.

You have to use another method to get a formatted date, **after** you've used the above method:

```
- (NSString *)stringFromDate: (NSDate *)date
```

If you want the reserve, you can use the other method of `NSDateFormatter`:

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString: (NSString *)string
```

Hope that helps.